# How to transclude all tiddlers tagged with current title

Tags: syntax, transclusion, tiddlywiki, tiddlywiki5

I see that I can transclude tiddlers with a specific tag using

```
<$list filter="[tag[TagNameHere]]">
! <$transclude field="title"/>
<$transclude mode="block"/>
```

I can also [make lists of tiddlers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43035772/4212158) tagged with the current title using `<currentTiddler>`:

```
<<list-links filter:"[tag<currentTiddler>] +[sort[title]]">>
```

However, if I try to combine the use of `<currentTiddler>` with the first macro, it doesn't work:

```
<$list filter="[tag[<currentTiddler>]]">
! <$transclude field="title"/>
<$transclude mode="block"/>
```

I've tried using the same `tag<currentTiddler>` syntax from the second macro, but TiddlyWiki complains about missing the brackets.

What is the correct syntax for transcluding using the current tiddler title? Bonus points for explaining why this syntax is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out:

```
<$list filter="[tag{!!title}]">
<h1><$link><$transclude field="title"/></$link></h1>
<$transclude mode="block"/>
</$list>
```

the `<h1>...</h1>` line includes the title of the transcluded tiddler as a linked header, which is nice.

[Credit](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/TiddlyWiki/<$24list$20filter$3D"[tag%7B!!title%7D]">|sort:relevance/tiddlywiki/V-sEk0nULSI/KFbOQ3vmEwAJ)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another filter that will also work: `[all[current]tagging[]]`